# WCF client response always NULL using ServiceModel Channel

Tags: c#, soap, asp.net-core

I am using .NET Core 2.1 to integrate with a legacy SOAP webservice we have.

**C# code**

```
[DataContract(Name = "registerResponse", Namespace = "urn:svcnet")]
public class RegisterResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "sessionKey")]
    public string SessionKey { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract(Name = "svcnet", Namespace = "urn:svcnet")]
public interface IRegister
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "register")]
    RegisterResponse Register(string param1);
}

public class MyContext
{
    public void Register()
    {
        var serviceUrl = "https://myserviceurl";

        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(serviceUrl));

        var factory = new ChannelFactory<IRegister>(binding, endpoint);

        IRegister channel = factory.CreateChannel();

        var result = channel.Register("somevalue"); // <<< result is always null
    }
}
```

**XML returned from the server (captured via Fiddler)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:svc="urn:svcnet">
  <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
  <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <svc:registerResponse>
      <sessionKey>ABC123</sessionKey>
    </svc:registerResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The result is always null. After spending many hours on Google and Stack Overflow I convinced myself that it's silently failing to construct the response object. Any clues how to debug it, or is there anything obviously wrong with my code?

**I also tried the following, but same result (always null)**

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "svcnet", Namespace = "urn:svcnet")]
public interface IRegister
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "register")]
    [return: MessageParameter(Name = "sessionKey")]
    string Register(string param1);
}
```

Comment: Nothing obvious to me but maybe 'registerResponse' vs 'RegisterResponse'?

Comment: @HansKilian thanks for your reply, I've tried both 'registerResponse' and 'RegisterResponse', same result. I'll update my question.

Comment: Your sessionKey doesn't have a namespace prefix, yet you defined it in the `RegisterResponse` class. If you don't want to use prefixes, you will have to declare it as a default namespace: `<registerResponse xmlns="urn:svcnet">`

Comment: Alternatively, if you can't change the remote Soap service: clear the namespace for SessionKey: `[DataMember(Name = "sessionKey", Namespace = "")]`

Comment: I can't change the server, however `Namespace` is not a a member of `DataMember`

Comment: I suggest you try [Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide)